# install packages based on spec-list conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have generate a spec-list below with `conda list --explicit > spec-list.txt`

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
@EXPLICIT
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/conda-env-2.6.0-1.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/_libgcc_mutex-0.1-conda_forge.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/_sysroot_linux-64_curr_repodata_hack-3-haa98f57_10.tar.bz2
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/blas-1.0-mkl.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ca-certificates-2021.10.26-h06a4308_2.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/intel-openmp-2021.2.0-h06a4308_610.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/ld_impl_linux-64-2.35.1-h7274673_9.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/libgcc-devel_linux-64-9.3.0-hb95220a_17.conda
```

I know I could create an environment of it using:

```
conda create --name python-course --file spec-list.txt
```

But I want to install this list into base environment.However, nothing happened. Could any one help? Thanks!

```
$ conda install --name base --file spec-list.txt
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a bad idea to do this with Conda's **base**,<sup>**1**</sup> however, to install additional packages with a specification list, one uses the `conda update` command, e.g.

```bash
conda update -n foo --file spec-list.txt
```

---

<sub>**[1]** For example, even in that little snippet shared by OP, we see a `conda-env` package. That package has been deprecated for years and will potentially conflict with a contemporary version of `conda`, which now packages both `conda` and `conda-env` Python modules.</sub>